# Animate images with steam like a cup of tea

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-animate

I have made this: [jsfiddle.net/BWncv/](http://jsfiddle.net/BWncv/)
I have a cup of tea with steam. I want to animate this steam. But this animation is not going well.

The steam must be animated up and up and up. Like steam from the top of a cup of tea. You can see it in the link.

How can I fix it so that the smoke is well animated?

You can change the code on js fiddle and update it.

Comment: one thing I noticed is that the function anim has 3 animations making 3 callbacks to anim, that means you will have 3 animations, then 9 then 27 etc...

Comment: I dont know. The script must be animate the smoke. But now the animate going top and then back. This is not good. The smoke must going top and top and top. Like a animation of smoke.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Try this ([demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Whu2m/1/)):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>js</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <style type="text/css">

      #viewport {
        position: relative;

        width: 400px;
        height: 300px;

        margin: 100px auto;
        border: 1px solid #333333;

        overflow: hidden;
      }

      #viewport .smoke {
        position: absolute;
        width: 20px;
        height: 40px;
        background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
      }

      #viewport .smoke1 {
        left: 140px;
        top: 260px;
      }

      #viewport .smoke2 {
        left: 180px;
        top: 260px;
      }

      #viewport .smoke3 {
        left: 220px;
        top: 260px;
      }
    </style>
  </head>

  <body>
    <div id="viewport">
      <div class="smoke smoke1"></div>
      <div class="smoke smoke2"></div>
      <div class="smoke smoke3"></div>
    </div>

    <script type="text/javascript">
      (function () {
        "use strict";

        $('#viewport .smoke').each(function ns () {
          var initialTop = $(this).position().top;

          $(this).animate({
            top: - $(this).height()
          }, Math.random() * 2000 + 2000, function () {
            $(this).css({
              top: initialTop,
              opacity: 0
            });
          }).animate({
            opacity: 1
          }, ns);
        });
      }());
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

A little extra demo here http://jsfiddle.net/nRas9/1/ which fully randomizes the elements.

---

My final code, a little complicated though:

http://jsfiddle.net/Fbtug/32/  (updated thanks to Luke Stanley)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>js</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <style type="text/css">
      #viewport {
        position: relative;
        width: 1000px;
        height: 600px;
        margin: 100px auto;
        border: 1px solid #333333;
        overflow: hidden;
        background: transparent url("http://www.mikevierwind.nl/images/bg-selection.jpg") no-repeat 0px -29px;
      }

      #viewport .smoke {
        position: absolute;
        width: 215px;
        height: 410px;
        bottom: 230px;
        left: 90px;
      }

      .smoke1 {
        background: transparent url("http://www.mikevierwind.nl/images/stoom1.png");
      }

      .smoke2 {
        background: transparent url("http://www.mikevierwind.nl/images/stoom2.png");
      }

      .smoke3 {
        background: transparent url("http://www.mikevierwind.nl/images/stoom3.png");
      }
    </style>
  </head>

  <body>
    <div id="viewport">
      <img
        src="http://www.mikevierwind.nl/images/bg-selection-carousel.png"
        width="2610"
        height="600"
        alt=""
        class="carousel-image"
      />
    </div>

    <script type="text/javascript">
      (function () {
        "use strict";

        var i = 0;
        for (; i < 3; i += 1) {
          setTimeout((function (idx) {
            return function addSmoke () {
              var
                time = 7500,
                smoke = $('<div />', {
                  class: 'smoke smoke' + (idx + 1),
                  css: {
                    opacity: 0
                  }
                });

              // add to viewport
              $(smoke).appendTo('#viewport');

              // animate
              $.when(
                // animate to 100% opacity in some part of the total time (fade in)
                $(smoke).animate({
                  opacity: 1
                }, {
                  duration: time * 0.2,
                  easing: 'linear',
                  queue: false,

                  // animate to 0% opacity in the remaining time (fade out)
                  complete: function () {
                    $(smoke).animate({
                      opacity: 0
                    }, {
                      duration: time * 0.8,
                      easing: 'linear',
                      queue: false
                    });
                  }
                }),

                // animate movement
                $(smoke).animate({
                  bottom: $('#viewport').height()
                }, {
                  duration: time,
                  easing: 'linear',
                  queue: false
                })

              // when all done, remove and add new random smoke
              ).then(function () {
                $(smoke).remove();
                addSmoke();
              });
            };
          }(i % 3)), i * 2500);
        }
      }());
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Great work. Would add some opacity when it reaches the top so it fades out. But gread work!

Comment: Just to show how easy Yoshi's example is to implement: http://jsfiddle.net/BWncv/1/ - you should ofcourse do it on the elements, not the container, and make it rounded in the bottom of the smoke.

Comment: I made it more exciting http://jsfiddle.net/reigel/BWncv/3/show
hahaha +1 btw... ;)

Comment: The images from mikevierwind.nl are 404ing so I played with it a bit, with CSS gradient and a new tea cup image: http://jsfiddle.net/Fbtug/32/

Answer (score 2):

Some awesome answers and here a  sample too using `animate` to alter the top and the opacity: ([Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/kFfT2/))

```
smoke1.animate({                
top: -500,
opacity: 0.5,
}, 7000, function(){
    smoke1.css({'top':300,'opacity':1})
    smoke1Animate();
});
```

Of course stretching out the top so the opacity fades in view.

Kicking off the animations at different times as to make them fade in gradually:

```
smoke1Animate();  
setTimeout(function(){ smoke2Animate(); },2000);
setTimeout(function(){smoke3Animate(); },4000);
```

And then of course calling themselves when they are finished.

Answer (score 0):

You need to make the smoke rise off the viewable area or fade out at its apex, hide it, then reset it's starting height (top or top-margin, depending on your method) property to make it show up back at the bottom and fade it in again. Do this to all three images, and it will seem like the steam is perpetually rising. Or, make an animated gif to put in the foreground.

Comment: How can i do this with javascript. Sorry i am beginnning javascripter..... Thanks for help. You can see my code on jsfiddle. In the link in my first post

Comment: @Yoshi did exactly what I was talking about. Also, don't worry about being a beginner, you'll be kicking butt in no time, and everyone was a beginner at some point.